# Spring 3 Annotated Configuration Picks up @Configuration and @Component but not @Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, annotations

So I'm trying to configure my web app without XML and go the all annotated route. I have a few classes annotated with @Configuration and @Component that are getting picked up automatically, but for some reason my @Controller annotations aren't being recognized and mapped to their corresponding @RequestMapping values.

My web.xml file looks like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="com-timbuk2-webapp-compositor" 
         version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" >

    <display-name>timbuk2-webapp-Compositor</display-name>

    <!-- Context Parameters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/log4j-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>com.company.webapp</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Listeners -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Filters -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>urlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
            <param-value>commons</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>confPath</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/urlrewrite-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <!-- Filter Mappings -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>urlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Servlets -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Servlet mappings -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

My main @Configuration class looks like so:

```
package com.company.webapp.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration
{    
    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource()
    {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename( "/WEB-INF/resources/messages" );
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds( 0 );
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass( JstlView.class );
        viewResolver.setPrefix( "/WEB-INF/views/" );
        viewResolver.setSuffix( ".jsp" );
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

My @Controller and @Component classes all live under the same package. For instance, here's a @Controller class from my app:

```
package com.company.webapp.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping( value = "/render" )
public class RenderController
{
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( getClass() );

    @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public ModelAndView handleGet( BindingResult bindingResult )
    {
        ... eventually return a ModelAndView object...
    }
}
```

So to reiterate, my @Controller classes aren't being mapped to the URLs I'm specifying. When the app starts up or reloads in my local tomcat environment I'm not seeing the usual "Mapped URL "/render" to..." console output.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing that might prevent my @Controller annotated classes not to be found and registered?

Comment: You add a single basename: messageSource.setBasename( "/WEB-INF/resources/messages" ); How to add multiple basenames with messageSource.setBasenames() ? It says array of basenames, but I'm not sure how to put a array in param.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this happens because `@Controller`s should be picked by `DispatcherServlet` from its own application context (which is loaded from `<servletname>-servlet.xml` by default), when your `contextClass` and `contextConfigLocation` are applied to the root context (the `ContextLoaderListener`'s one, which is loaded from `applicationContext.xml` by default).

To configure `DispatcherServlet`s application context, you should set `contextClass` and `contextConfigLocation` as the servlet's `init-param`s.

**EDIT:**
This behaviour is controlled by the property `detectHandlersInAncestorContexts` of `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`, so the alternative approach is to set it to `true` during configuration:

```
@Bean
public DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping mapping() {
    DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping m = new DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping();
    m.setDetectHandlersInAncestorContexts(true);
    return m;
}
```

Comment: I set the contextClass and contextConfigLocation parameters of the dispatcher servlet to the same values as the webapp. All seems well, I guess now I'm a little confused though. Is there two contexts running now? Before, when I was doing all XML configuration, the URL mappings would register when I would start or reload the web app. Now they don't get mapped until the first incoming request is made.

Comment: 1) Yes, you have two application context - the root context and the DispatcherServlet`s context, which is a child of the root one. This is typical for Spring MVC applications, see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet. However, it's not a good idea to make them load the annotation-based configuration from the same package - beans would be duplicated. 2) DispatcherServlet's context is initialized when servlet is loaded, so you can control in with `<load-on-startup>`. 3) I added the alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your mvc dispatcher servlet xml file where the package should be for all the controllers to be scanned for @controller or @Component.

```xml
<context:component-scan
        base-package="packagesseperatedbycomma" />
```

Comment: he specifically said he wants xml-less configuration

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue but adding the following code to my web.xml:

```xml
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>org.xxxx.inquiry.config, org.xxxx.inquiry.controller</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

But doing this I tell it where to look for my controllers